# Why would square rooting the size of the alphabet decrease the storage size of a trie by 8 and not 16?

Tags: algorithms

From wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) on trie's:

> There are several ways to represent tries, corresponding to different
>   trade-offs between memory use and speed of the operations. The basic
>   form is that of a linked set of nodes, where each node contains an
>   array of child pointers, one for each symbol in the alphabet (so for
>   the English alphabet, one would store 26 child pointers and for the
>   alphabet of bytes, 256 pointers). This is simple but wasteful in terms
>   of memory: using the alphabet of bytes (size 256) and four-byte
>   pointers, each node requires a kilobyte of storage, and when there is
>   little overlap in the strings' prefixes, the number of required nodes
>   is roughly the combined length of the stored strings.[2]:341 Put
>   another way, the nodes near the bottom of the tree tend to have few
>   children and there are many of them, so the structure wastes space
>   storing null pointers.[12]
>
> **> The storage problem can be alleviated by an implementation technique
>   called alphabet reduction, whereby the original strings are
>   reinterpreted as longer strings over a smaller alphabet. E.g., a
>   string of n bytes can alternatively be regarded as a string of 2n
>   four-bit units and stored in a trie with sixteen pointers per node.
>   Lookups need to visit twice as many nodes in the worst case, but the
>   storage requirements go down by a factor of eight.[2]:347–352**

I must be making some simple math mistake:
The 8 bit alphabet has $2^{8n}$ bottom nodes with $2^{8}*4$ bytes storage each. The 4 bit alphabet also has $2^{4*2n}$ bottom nodes with $2^{4}*4$ bytes storage each. Why does wikipedia say a factor of 8 storage difference and not 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your quote speaks about "bottom nodes" it doesn't mean *leaf* nodes -- just nodes that are sufficiently far down the tree that most of them have only a single child.

If you switch from an 8-bit alphabet to a 4-bit alphabet, each node now contains an array of 16 child pointers rather than an array of 256 child pointers. That's a reduction by a factor of 16 -- but on the other hand, you now need twice as many nodes to represent strings of the same length. That halves the savings.